# Is the 10's complement operation defined for a negative decimal number?

Tags: number-theory

Two decimal numbers $X$ and $Y$ are considered to be 10's complements of each other if:
$$X + Y = 10^n$$
Where $n$ is the number of digits in $X$ and $Y$ .

For e.g $               $
10's complement of 
$417 = 1000 -417 = 583$

DOUBT : Is the 10's complement operation defined for negative numbers?

Since from the above definition, $Y$ for $X=-417$ would be $1417$. But then $n$ would become 4 and it would be violation.

Note : I am talking about 10's complement as an operation and not as a representation for signed numbers.

EDIT : The "same no. of digits " property in the definition seems to be wrong . Please provide the correct definition of 10's Complement and answer the question on the basis of that .Thanks.

Comment: If you decided that your $10$'s complement had to be reflexive then the answer would be no, in the same way that for $X=97$ you might consider $Y=3$ but then reject it as the $10$'s complement of $3$ would be $7$ not $97$

Comment: I see. I found this definition in a research paper somewhere. I would really appreciate if you could give your(standard or well known) definition of 10's complement and calculate the same for a negative number according to that definition @Henry . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your definition, negative numbers do not have complements. This is because if $10^{k-1}<n<10^k$, then the complement of $-n$ would be the number $10^k - (-n) = 10^k + n$ (since $n$ has $k$ digits), but $10^k - n$ has $k+1$ digits, leading to a contradiction.

Comment: How is complement of $-n$, $10^{k} -n$ ? Is n positive ? If it is positive then  $10^{k} -n$ has $k$ digits IMO .

Moreover , you are welcome to provide any definition 10's complement and tell me the same for a negative number for the same definition. Thanks.

Comment: @AtulGangwar I was getting ahead of myself. It's fixed now.

Comment: Please pay heed to this " Moreover , you are welcome to provide any definition 10's complement and tell me the same for a negative number for the same definition". @5xum

Comment: Please! help :D

Comment: @AtulGangwar Well, you could say that for negative numbers, the complement of $-n$ is the negative of the complement of $n$, but I don't know if that is helpful to you...

Comment: Nah! the 10's complement of a negative number has no meaning. It only makes sense when we are talking about 10's complement representation of signed numbers, where it would give back the representation of the positive number. My doubt was due to an erroneous question. Thanks for your effort .